REST + GraphQL Api in NET 8 does not work properly on IIS
I have a minimal API that includes both REST and GraphQL endpoints, built with .NET 8, NSwag 14, and HotChocolate 13.9. Everything works wonderfully when debugging in Visual Studio, but issues arise when I publish it on my local IIS. I published the API under a subdirectory of the Default IIS website ("Security").
The Swagger UI displays correctly and loads the specification JSON file, but the request URL is incorrect. Instead of using "localhost/Security/api...", it uses "localhost/api...".
For HotChocolate, the UI shows up, but it can't load the schema due to the same issue—the request URL doesn't include the site name.
've tried setting the path base with app.UsePathBase("/Security/api"); and experimenting with routing for Swagger and GraphQL in my Program.cs file, but nothing works.
Here is how my Program.cs file looks:
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Security.Infrastructure;
using Security.Web.GraphQL.Mutation;
using Security.Web.GraphQL.Query;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options 
    => options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.All);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
builder.Services.AddApplicationDbContext(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddWebServices();

// Add HealthChecks
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddDbContextCheck<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddQueryType<UsersQuery>()
    .AddMutationType<UsersMutation>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseForwardedHeaders();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    await app.InitialiseDatabaseAsync();
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

//app.UsePathBase("/Security/api");
app.UseSwaggerUi();
app.UseSwaggerUi(settings =>
{
    settings.Path = "/api";
    settings.DocumentPath = "api/specification.json";
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.UseExceptionHandler(options => { });

app.Map("/", () => Results.Redirect("/api"));

var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

app.MapEndpoints(assembly);

app.MapGraphQL();

app.Run();

One more important detail: my endpoints use the MapGroup extension to group them. The setup looks like this:
app.MapGroup($"/api/{groupName}")

Here is the full code of the application: Security
If anyone could provide a hint, I would greatly appreciate it.
One more thing, the rest API works with a different client, e.g. Postman


I make some changes in your program.cs file, could you click the link and check it. Waiting for your updates.

Hi @Jason Pan. The API did not even start. An extract of the logs:
...
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1000]
No candidates found for the request path '/api'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[2]
Request did not match any endpoints
....
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1000]
No candidates found for the request path '/graphql'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[2]
Request did not match any endpoints

In theory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0), it should suffice with app.UsePathBase("/Security"); , but this is not the case. One more approach here (https://andrewlock.net/using-pathbase-with-dotnet-6-webapplicationbuilder/) bur no luck

Hi Sergio, do you mind create a brand new repo which can reproduce the issue for us ? The repo you shared we can't debug it directly, it use same services. I guess the issue not related to GraphQL, you don't need to add GraphQL in your new sample project.

And please hide your sensitive data, it will keep your data safely.

I greatly appreciate you taking the time to check the code @Jason Pan. It will take me a little while to reproduce the error since the API has several other dependencies. Thank you also for the reminder about the sensitive data. For this repository, I intentionally left it open so others can understand the sources.

Partial answer:
The issue with the GraphQL endpoint was related to the return type of the mutation. I was trying to return an IResult, which GraphQL does not recognize. Now, GraphQL works in a subdirectory of my localhost, and I hope it will be the same with a DNS.
Since I do not intend to use a Swagger page in production, I will leave it as it is for now. I can use the REST endpoint without issues from a different client.
While it would be helpful to understand the issue with my NSwag configuration, my primary focus is on the GraphQL endpoint. Therefore, I will not spend more time investigating.
